# Removed JDK6, installed JDK7. JAVA_HOME broke and javac not installed

Tags: java, software-installation, openjdk, jdk, oracle

I am finding that the `javac` is not in the `java-7-openjdk-i386` package.

*Problem 1:*

```
$ javac    
The program 'javac' can be found in the following packages:    
 * default-jdk    
 * ecj    
 * gcj-4.6-jdk    
 * openjdk-6-jdk    
 * gcj-4.5-jdk    
 * openjdk-7-jdk    
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

*Problem 2 :*

So I decided to try installing the JEE from Oracle.

But, Oracle JEE  is not hosted in the PPA because that's not allowed by the new Java license (which is also the reason why it has been removed from the official Ubuntu repositories); the package in the PPA automatically downloads Oracle Java JDK 7 from its official website and installs it on your Ubuntu / Linux Mint computer, just like the flashplugin-installer package does.

First, what is a PPA?

I downloaded `java_ee_sdk-7-web-jdk7-linux.sh` into the `/usr/lib/jvm` directory.
And tried to uncompress it.

```
$ sudo sh ./java_ee_sdk-7-web-jdk7-linux.sh    
Could not locate a suitable jar utility.    
Please ensure that you have Java 7 or newer installed on your system and accessible in your PATH or by setting JAVA_HOME.
```

*Problem 3 :*

```
$ echo  $JAVA_HOME   
/usr/lib/jvm/default-java

$ java -version    
java version "1.7.0_25"    
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.10) (7u25-2.3.10-1ubuntu0.12.04.2)    
OpenJDK Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
```

What I think happened was that I removed JDK6 and the `default-java` which was a link to the installation went with it.

So the `$JAVA_HOME` now points to nothing and it needs to point to `java-7-openjdk-i386` package.

What is the solution for this?

Comment: @123456 Please write up your solution as an answer. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

JDK 7 is in [main ubuntu repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=quantal&section=all&arch=any&keywords=javac&searchon=contents). You dont need extra PPAs or difficult compilation methods to install.

JDK7 can be installed by:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-6-jdk openjdk-7-jre openjdk-6-jre openjdk-7-jre-headless openjdk-6-jre-headless libgeronimo-jpa-2.0-spec-java openjdk-7-source openjdk-7-jre-lib openjdk-7-demo openjdk-6-source openjdk-6-jre-lib openjdk-6-demo openjdk-7-doc openjdk-6-doc jarwrapper
```

Comment: Installing both OpenJDK 6 and 7 might cause OpenJDK 6 to be set to be the default.  `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk` should be sufficient.